# Launching a Shell Script via .desktop in Raspbian Wheezy

Tags: bash, debian, shell-script, raspberry-pi

I am trying to launch OMXplayer and play a sequence of videos on loop on a RaspberryPi running  Raspbian Wheezy. I have got a working shell script which launches and plays the videos courtesy of http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/looping-video-playlist-omxplayer-raspberry-pi/

I have this placed in /home/pi/ and it is executable. I have created a file testsh.desktop in /usr/share/applications/ which I have also made executable. This file contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
Name=Play
Comment=Plays videos
Exec=/home/pi/playvideos.sh
Categories=Application;
```

I have also tried setting exec as:

```
Exec=lxterminal --command "/home/pi/playvideos.sh"
```

This isn't working and I guess I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Weird, it works ok in KDE, but not on my Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work if you have `Terminal=true`, it runs

`x-terminal-emulator  "/home/pi/playvideos.sh"`

`x-terminal-emulator` is `lxterminal` which needs `--command` to run a command

Either:

Set `Terminal=false` and run the script with

`Exec=lxterminal --command "/home/pi/playvideos.sh"`

as you tried before.

Or:

Set `Terminal=true` and run the script with

`Exec=--command "/home/pi/playvideos.sh"`